# How to get number of affected rows in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have one question concerning Python and the sqlalchemy module. What is the equivalent for `cursor.rowcount` in the sqlalchemy Python?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`ResultProxy` objects have a [`rowcount`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount) property as well.

Comment: `rowcount` is not actually the count of *affected rows*. See my answer for detail.

Comment: The docs do include `rowcount` these days: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount

Answer (score 32):

Actually there is **no way** to know this precisely for postgres.

The closes thing is `rowcount`. But
`rowcount` is **not** the number of affected rows. Its the number of matched rows. See what [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.BaseCursorResult.rowcount) says

> This attribute returns the number of rows *matched*, which is not necessarily the same as the number of rows that were actually *modified* - an UPDATE statement, for example, may have no net change on a given row if the SET values given are the same as those present in the row already. Such a row would be matched but not modified. On backends that feature both styles, such as MySQL, `rowcount` is configured by default to return the match count in all cases

So for both of the following scenarios `rowcount` will report `1`. Because of `Rows matched: 1`

1. one row changed with `update` statement.

   ```
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
    Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
   ```
2. same `update` statement is executed.

   ```
    Query OK, 0 row affected (0.00 sec)
    Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
   ```

Comment: So what's the answer to OP's question?

Comment: Although this useful insight clarifies a misconception, it does not provide a helpful answer to this question... If there is no answer, then it should also be specified. Thank you

Comment: I haven't found any answer on this yet. But later realized that actual affected number of rows is implementation detail.  Rather it's important that it ensures `rowcount` amount of rows are in the requested updated state.

Answer (score 5):

Shiplu's analysis is 100% correct.

Pushing the discussion a bit further, here is how to display the **updated** rowcount and not the **matched** rowcount using sqlalchemy for MySQL: the engine needs to be created with the flag `client_flag=0`.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(
    'mysql+pymysql://user:password@host:port/db', 
    connect_args={'client_flag':0}
)
```

To give a bit more details, the `rowcount` returned by MySQL depends on the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` flag provided to the C-API function `mysql_real_connect()` as stated in [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

> For UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value by default is the number of rows actually changed. If you specify the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flag to mysql_real_connect() when connecting to mysqld, the affected-rows value is the number of rows “found”; that is, matched by the WHERE clause.

The flag value is 2 ([MySQL constants](https://github.com/google/mysql/blob/c01fc2134d439282a21a2ddf687566e198ddee28/include/mysql_com.h#L211)), and is added automatically by sqlalchemy when creating the `engine` as visible [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/03989d1dce80999bb9ea1a7d36df3285e5ce4c3b/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py#L267-L274.).

The value of `client_flag` in `connect_args` allows to override this value.

Note: this might break sth from the `sane_rowcount` (only used in the ORM apparently) - in my case, I only use the Core of sqlalchemy. In last link:

```
# FOUND_ROWS must be set in CLIENT_FLAGS to enable
# supports_sane_rowcount.
```

Answer (score 2):

What Shiplu says is correct of course, however, to answer the question, in many cases you can easily make the matched columns equal the changed columns by including the condition that the value is different in the WHERE clause, i.e.:

```
UPDATE table
SET column_to_be_changed = "something different"
WHERE column_to_be_changed != "something different" AND [...your other conditions...]
```

`rowcount` will then return the number of affected rows, because it equals the number of matched rows.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is something similar for postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .returning to give you the rows which have been updated, and then use result.rowcount to count this
eg

```
insertstmt = insert(mytable).values(myvalues).returning(mytable.c.mytableid)

with get_engine().begin() as conn:
        result = conn.execute(insertstmt)
        print(result.rowcount)
```