# How do I get the number of rows affected with SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I get the number of rows affected for an update statement with sqlalchemy? (I am using mysql and python/pyramid):

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.base import ResultProxy

@classmethod
def myupdate(cls, id, myvalue):
    DBSession.query(cls).filter(cls.id == id).update({'mycolumn': myvalue})
    if ResultProxy.rowcount == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Note: I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702342/how-to-get-number-of-affected-rows-in-sqlalchemy) but according to [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.rowcount): "The ‘rowcount’ reports the number of rows matched by the WHERE criterion of an UPDATE or DELETE statement."....in other words, it doesn't return the number of rows *affected* by the update or delete statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this behaviour by specifying the right option to the DBAPI, according to [the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#rowcount-support).

I don't have a mysql ready to test, but I think adding the right option (either `client_flag` or `found_rows=False` depending on the api used) to the configuration url should do the trick. Check the corresponding source for [mysqlconnector](https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/b4fdcb0c3303/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py?at=default#cl-96) and [oursql](https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/b4fdcb0c3303/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/oursql.py?at=default#cl-219) for more info.

I hope this will be enough to help you.

Comment: trying to figure it out. I have no idea where I would change that. I am a newb to pyramid, sqlalchemy and python.

Comment: you have somewhere a config url for the database, somthing like ``mysql+mysqlconnector://user:passwd@host/db`` you can add some arguments at the end like you would in a get request : ``mysql+mysqlconnector://user:passwd@host/db?found_rows=False``

Comment: I get an error: "'found_rows' is an invalid keyword argument for this function None None"

Comment: Oh, sorry, it seems I mixed up those two. Could you try `mysql+oursql://user:passwd@host/db?found_rows=False` ?

Comment: added that but the addition of oursql makes any queries slooooow. I tried testing it but am frustrated by the slowness. Setting found_rows=False does not seem to do the trick

Comment: That must be because you now use another DBAPI. If it's really slow, would restoring the original configuration and add `DBSession.query(cls).filter(cls.id == id).filter(cls.mycolumn != myvalue).count()` queries be faster ? (You can probably factor the two queries in one function is you want to avoid code duplication).