# sqlalchemy - how can I get update method result?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I execute `update` method:

```
# connect db to get `conn`
# get metadate which is table `account`
u = account.update().where(account.c.ID == 9).values(USERNAME='k9')
r = conn.execute(u)
```

How can I get the `update` is success or not?
I checked the doc, but not found...

Or maybe I just do not care this??

`r` is a `ResultProxy`, `update` action do auto-commit and close.

THX:)

---

APPEND

THX @Lucas Kahlert's answer, good point!

`rowcount` satisfy my question's situation.

[doc-rowcount](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy.rowcount)

```
This attribute returns the number of rows matched, 
which is not necessarily the same as the number of rows that were actually modified

In [7]: u = account.update().\
        where( and_((account.c.ID == 4), (account.c.PWD =='4297f44b1'))).\
        values(PWD='hahahaha')

In [8]: print u
UPDATE `ACCOUNT` SET `PWD`=%s WHERE `ACCOUNT`.`ID` = %s AND `ACCOUNT`.`PWD` = %s

In [11]: rst = conn.execute(u)

In [12]: rst.rowcount  # found row and did update action
Out[12]: 1L

In [13]: rst = conn.execute(u)

In [14]: rst.rowcount  # found row but value is same, so do not do update action
Out[14]: 0L
```

Comment: query.update() will return 0 for no row updated or 1 (or any positive integer) for the number of rows successfully affected/updated. (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check, how many rows are effected by your query using the `rowcount` attribute of the `ResultProxy`. The `rowcount` tells you, how many rows are matched by your `WHERE` condition. This is not the same as the affected rows (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827519/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-affected-with-sql-alchemy)), but should do the job in your case.

#### No row is affected

If no row is matched by your condition, the query will be executed regardless if data in the `UPDATE` statement is correct or not.

#### Constraint violation

If rows are matched and you try to update a row with an invalid set of data, SQLAlchemy will raise an constraint violation exception (eg. `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError`). In this case you could catch the exception and use this for your "success" check.

If no constraint violation occured during your `UPDATE`, the statement silently succeeds.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

class User(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s','%s', '%s')>" % (self.name, self.fullname, self.password)

# create a connection to a in-memory sqlite database
# turn echo on to see the auto-generated SQL
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

# this is used to keep track of tables and their attributes
metadata = MetaData()
account = Table('account', metadata,
                Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True),
                Column('USERNAME', String, unique=True))

# create the table and tell it to create it in the  database engine that is
# passed
metadata.create_all(engine)

# create a mapping between the account and the User class
mapper(User, account)

# populate database
engine.execute(account.insert().values(ID=9,  USERNAME='account-9'))
engine.execute(account.insert().values(ID=10, USERNAME='account-10'))

result = engine.execute(account.update().where(account.c.ID==9).values(USERNAME='k9'))
print('Matched rows:', result.rowcount) # 1

# This query will succeed, because there is not row with ID 20. It does not
# matter, if the USERNAME 'k9' is invalid (because there is already a 'k9')
result = engine.execute(account.update().where(account.c.ID==20).values(USERNAME='k9'))
print('Matched rows:', result.rowcount) # 0


# Constraint violation
# 
# will raise an:
#   sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
#       (IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: account.USERNAME
#       'UPDATE account SET "USERNAME"=? WHERE account."ID" = ?' ('k9', 10)
result = engine.execute(account.update().where(account.c.ID==10).values(USERNAME='k9'))
```