# Returning Number of affected rows from SQL Server with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy to make changes to a table in SQL Server database, and would like to get back number of affected rows.

I know there is `.rowcount` attribute to `ResultProxy`, but as, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43538254/4077912) answer is demonstrating `.rowcount` is not necessarily the same as number of affected rows.

SQL Server uses [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) to access number of affected rows from the previous statement execution.

Is there a way to modify an sqlalchemy expression that uses insert / update statement to end with `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`?

For example, given:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, create_engine

url = 'mssql+pyodbc://dsn'
engine = create_engine(url)

metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('fullname', String),
)

ins = users.insert().values(name='jack', fullname='Jack Jones')
upd1 = users.update().values(fullname='Jack Doe').where(users.c.name == 'jack')
upd2 = users.update().values(fullname='Jack Doe').where(users.c.name == 'jack')
```

I could prepend `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to an `update` statement:

```
sel = select([text('@@ROWCOUNT')])

sql1 = sel.suffix_with(upd2)

print(sql1.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
```

Yielding "wrong" query:

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT UPDATE users SET fullname='Jack Doe' WHERE users.name = 'jack'
```

Trying to do the "right" thing:

```
sql2 = upd2.suffix_with(sel)
```

Raises `AttributeError` since 'Update' object has no attribute 'suffix_with'.

So is there a way to get desired sql query:

```
UPDATE users SET fullname='Jack Doe' WHERE users.name = 'jack';
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Using sql expression language without fully textual constructs.