# Get amount of inserted rows using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I`m writing a code to update my database and I would like to get the number of rows that were inserted after my commit, how can I do this?

```
for table, endpoint in ENDPOINTS.items():
    url = BASE_URL + endpoint
    response = get_response(url)

    table_object = getattr(Base.classes, table)

    self.add_missing_data(response, table_object, session)

session.commit()
print('Total rows added: {}'.format(xxxxx))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702342/how-to-get-number-of-affected-rows-in-sqlalchemy):

Here is your code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def add_mising_data(self, response, table_object, session):
    con = create_engine(...)
    # insert some data using 
    # con, response, table_object and session
    result_proxy = con.execute("INSERT ...")
    return result_proxy.rowcount # this is the number of inserted rows

# in your loop
total_num_row = 0
for table, endpoint in ENDPOINTS.items():
    url = BASE_URL + endpoint
    response = get_response(url)

    table_object = getattr(Base.classes, table)

    num_row = self.add_missing_data(response, table_object, session)
    total_num_row = total_num_row + num_row

print (total_num_row) # <-- here you are
```

Answer (score 0):

If `add_missing_data` is your defined method, you can just return the number of rows you have inserted inside it.

```
def add_missing_data(self, ...)
     rows = 0
     for i in data:
         # insert data code...

         rows += 1
     return rows
```

And then just sum them up.

```
total = 0
for table, endpoint in ENDPOINTS.items():
    total += self.add_missing_data(response, table_object, session)
session.commit()
print('Total rows added: {}'.format(total))
```

If you want something more dynamic, you can use sqlachemy events for [after_insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html?highlight=after_insert#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.after_insert) or [before_insert](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html?highlight=after_insert#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert)