# Is it possible to view the response message for SQL queries executed in Python via sqlalchemy engine.execute()?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

After executing a query like

```
resp = engine.execute('UPDATE my_table SET name = NULL WHERE id = 10')
```

I want to display the execution response such as

```
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.16 sec)
```

Is this response accessible through the ResultProxy object (ie `resp`)?

Comment: Isn't that message produced by the `mysql` client, not the DB itself? So in other words no (is my guess).

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes it is, just wondering if that is also stored in the ResultProxy.

Comment: Not the message, but similar information; see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702342/how-to-get-number-of-affected-rows-in-sqlalchemy. Note that by default it is the count of **matched** rows, not affected.